# Validate a youtube url including the shortened version with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, youtube-api

I need to validate a youtube video URL with javascript/jquery that works for all types of youtube video url's including the shortened youtu.be version. There are a wealth of examples on how to do this regex but they all fail to include the shortened version. Any ideas?

Comment: may be it is dub http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288941/validating-youtube-playlist-url-using-regex

Comment: maybe you didn't read my question and compare it to your link.

Answer (score 0):

The only supported way of validating YouTube watch page URLs (including youtu.be URLs) is using oEmbed: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/10/oembed-support.html